# JSoup can't parse IDs with an underscore

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm parsing an HTML document with JSoup and I've run in to a brick wall. It seems as though JSoup can not parse IDs that contain underscores. This is what I am doing:

```
for (Element table : doc.select("table.playerlist#powerplay_1_forwards")) {
  .....stuff.....
}
```

and it chokes up on it. I'm using version 1.8.3. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer... You have to use the getElementById() method on the Document to parse it, otherwise using select() will not work with IDs with an underscore